# CakePHP - Render views using elements vs ajax

Tags: ajax, cakephp, view, controller, element

If views from different controllers use the same element, requiring different controllers to pass the same datas (hence maybe doing the same processing) to the views, wouldn't it be better to make an AJAX call to a single controller?

Let's say we have this:

- Model/Post.php
- Model/User.php
- Model/Service.php
- Controllers/UsersController.php
- Controllers/ServicesController.php
- Views/Users/view.ctp
- Views/Services/view.ctp
- Views/Elements/list_users_post.ctp

A user belongs to a service, and a user has many posts.
In `Views/Services/view.ctp`, I want to display a list of each user of a particular service, and for each user, some related infos and a list of his 10 last posts.
In `Views/Users/view.ctp`, I want to display user's related infos and a list of his 10 lasts posts.
The element `Views/Elements/list_users_post.ctp` allows me to factor the code displaying a table of a user's posts. It needs the var `$userPostList` to be set, and to be structured the same as the result of `$this->Post->find('all', array('conditions' => array('user_id' => $userId)))`.
So in my `UsersController::view($userId)` and `ServicesController::view($serviceId)` actions, I end up with some duplicated code retrieving users' posts.

I thought to refactor the code so the action `ServicesController::view($serviceId)` don't make any find on Post model, but instead, the view `Services/index.ctp` makes AJAX calls to the action `UsersController::view($userId)` for each user. That way, no more duplicated code, but with the overhead of AJAX calls.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

A good way to avoid duplicate code in your case is to move it to the model layer. So instead of this in the controller:

```
$this->Post->find('all', array('conditions' => array('user_id' => $userId)))
```

You would have this in the controllers:

```
$this->Post->getUserPosts($userId);
```

And this in the **Post** model:

```
function getUserPosts($userId){
    return $this->find('all', array('conditions' => array('user_id' => $userId)));
}
```

AJAX calls are also a good solution but even with them it would be best to keep the business logic in the models if possible.

Other ways to avoid duplicate code include(but are not limited to):
Using Helpers in Views
Using Components in Controllers
Using Behaviors in Models

That should get you started on keeping your code DRY.

Comment: Yep, that's already what is done for some tricky find, requiring for example to request several models. But that won't prevent to put the same (as small as it can be) piece of code in multiple controllers. One of the other drawbacks of using elements is the variable forwarding... When you have nested elements, the top level ont must be given all variables needed for sub-elements, thus heavily coupling elements. I only see AJAX to prevent that, but, meh, I'm wondering of the overhead...